# Calculating kernel-density estimate in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, subset, kernel-density

I want to perform kernel-density estimate on a grid in parallel. There is some scaling involved and I can't figure out how to obtain the same results when performing the calculation on different threads.

To illustre this, I'm using an simple example from the scipy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def measure(n):
    "Measurement model, return two coupled measurements."
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2

m1, m2 = measure(2000)
xmin = m1.min()
xmax = m1.max()
ymin = m2.min()
ymax = m2.max()

kde_bandwith = 0.5

X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values, bw_method=kde_bandwith)
Z = np.reshape(kernel.evaluate(positions).T, X.shape)
```

I'm performing the last two lines on `n_split` subsets of the data (in practice this would be performed on different thread but here I kept a simple loop for simplicity):

```
## split
n_split = 10
values_split = np.array_split(values, n_split, axis=1)

results = []
for v in values_split:
    kernel_n = stats.gaussian_kde(v, bw_method=kde_bandwith)  
    Z_n = np.reshape(kernel_n.evaluate(positions).T, X.shape)
    results.append(Z_n)

Z2 = np.sum(results, axis=0)
```

here I'm simply recombining the results from each subset of data by summing the `Z_n` of each subset together into `Z2`.

Finally, a simple code to compare the results: left is the original version, middle is the result obtain from combining the subsets, and right the difference between the two.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,2), dpi=200)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)

c1 = ax1.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
          extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
#ax1.plot(m1, m2, 'k.', markersize=2)
ax1.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax1.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
plt.colorbar(c1, shrink=0.6)

c2 = ax2.imshow(np.rot90(Z2), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
          extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
#ax2.plot(m1, m2, 'k.', markersize=2)
ax2.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax2.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
plt.colorbar(c2, shrink=0.6)

c3 = ax3.imshow(np.rot90(Z2-Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
          extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax3.plot(m1, m2, 'k.', markersize=0.1)
ax3.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax3.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
plt.colorbar(c3, shrink=0.6)

plt.show()
```

[image: comparison]

Notes: It looks like the magnitude of the KDE is `n_split` larger, but by simply normalizing with `1/n_split` or even `len(values_split)/len(values)` (which in this case is equal), the results are not exactly the same, shown on the next figure as reference.

[image: comparison with scaling]